# refused to connect error when embedding a website with iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I was trying to embed a website (the full website) in HTML with iframe but I got an error when trying to embed the website.
[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) refused to connect.
My code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com" title="Example"></iframe>
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/ne4Lda1x/. Can you please describe more.

Comment: Post the request and response headers you see in the network tab of dev tools.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue while embedding a website in another website (Squarespace)
The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.
There are three possible directives for X-Frame-Options:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://toucan-springtail-bftp.squarespace.com/
```

I used the 3'd option and the URL after ALLOW-FROM is the URL of the website where you want to embed.

And it worked for me!

Comment: not able to understand where exactly we can add x-frame -options , is it in iframe slector?

Comment: You have to edit the whole headers for the whole site even if you just want this to work on a single page?